# Dagger with JUnit tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm new in writing android unit tests and faced with a problem of injecting some mock dependencies into my test class. I found a lot of articles how I can do it using "old" Dagger (version < 2.10), but nothing about Dagger with version > 2.10. I just want to write smth like that

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class) 
public class ConfigurationUnitTest {

    @Inject SomeDependency someDependency;

    public ConfigurationUnitTest() {
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
       //use someDependency variable here
    } 
}
```

But I didn't find any way to inject some dependencies into this Test class. Hope someone helps me. Thanks.

Comment: Wait, I'm a bit confused. What are you trying to do? Inject your tests or inject the classes you are testing?

Comment: Inject some dependency class into my Test class using Dagger > 2.10. It's quite easy to inject smth into Activity/Fragment/Service, but not into any other class.

Comment: well it's pretty much the same. You can follow this post https://proandroiddev.com/writing-espresso-instrumentation-tests-with-dagger2-kotlin-d30f12c4769b it pretty much explains how you can setup a test component and use it to inject the test dependencies.